# Insert multiple rows mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>View shopping cart</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>
<body>
<br>
<div id="books-wrapper">
<!-- #content to center the menu -->
<div id="content">
<!-- This is the actual menu -->
<ul id="darkmenu">
<li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="catalogue.php">Catalogue</a></li>
<li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
<li><a href= "view_cart.php">Cart</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
</ul>
<div id = "welcome" >
Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['login_user']?>! <br> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<h1 id = "mainHeader" >View Cart</h1>
<br>
<div class="view-cart">
<?php
$current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if(isset($_SESSION["books"]))
{
$total = 0;
echo '<form method="post" action="">';
echo '<ul>';
$cart_items = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION["books"] as $cart_itm){
$ISBN = $cart_itm["ISBN"];
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT Title,BookDesc,Price FROM books WHERE ISBN='$ISBN'");
$obj = $results->fetch_object();
echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["ISBN"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">×</a></span>';
echo '<div class="p-Price">'.$currency.$obj->Price.'</div>';
echo '<div class="book-info">';
echo '<h3>'.$obj->Title.' (ISBN :'.$ISBN.')</h3> ';
echo '<div class="p-quantity">Quantity : '.$cart_itm["quantity"].'</div>';
echo '<div>'.$obj->BookDesc.'</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</li>';
$subtotal = ($cart_itm["Price"]*$cart_itm["quantity"]);
$total = ($total + $subtotal);
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->Title.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$ISBN.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_desc['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->BookDesc.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_quantity['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$cart_itm["quantity"].'" />';
$cart_items ++;
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '<span class="check-out-txt">';
echo '<strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong> ';
echo '</span>';
echo '<button name="submit_btn" class="save_order">Save Order</button>';
echo '</form>';
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']) ){
$insquery = "INSERT INTO `pending_orders` (`OrderNo`,`BookName`,`Quantity`,`TotalPrice`,`ISBN`,`StudentID`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $obj->Title . "', '" . $cart_itm['quantity'] . "', '" . $total . "', '" . $ISBN . "', '" . $_SESSION['login_user'] . "');";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($insquery);
$stmt->execute();
}
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is supposed to save a customers book order into a database,  It works perfectly fine for ONE book. Line 76 to 81 has the insert statement.
however if the person has purchased two books then only the last book gets added to the database. Screenshots added:

This is what it looks like on my website. As you can see the person has selected two books to be purchased:
http://postimg.org/image/3kj1gvytx/
However this is what i get in my phpmyadmin site:
http://postimg.org/image/k85hs56xj/
We can see that only the second book (biology) gets stored in the database. as well as the total of the two books

Any ideas how i could fix the issue and store both books.

Thanks

Comment: In this case you can use Ajax asynchronous requests to add items without page refresh.

Comment: How would i do that? Ive never really used Ajax

Comment: Wait a minute (i will update here)...

Answer (score 0):

As you don't know Ajax, you can do something like this:
1) Reset $result array, to select items again for MySQL query.
2) With while loop insert each selected value into DB.

```
reset($result);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $ins = mysqli_query($con, "Here goes insert statement for each");
}
```

**EDIT**

```
$ISBN = $cart_itm["ISBN"];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","yourbasename");
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Title,BookDesc, Price FROM books    
WHERE ISBN='$ISBN'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
{
    $insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT.....");
}
```

Comment: Im assuming id put the code after the    if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']) ){  
line?

Comment: Getting an error that says unexpected { on line 79.

Comment: while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) -> i forgot one ")". try this with two "))"

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\view_cart.php on line 77

Comment: forget reset(), just make select query again and insert items, solution is to just loop through your array items and not to insert just one. so you can have your own implementation of this solution as you now the reason why you couldn't insert both books. :).

Comment: I got rid of result but still get two errors: "Undefined variable: result" and "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result"

Comment: you can upload your base and files on GitHub, because as I don't have full information, I can't help you. Maybe there is some error with db, or something else.

Comment: I dont have github account but i have copied the code to here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogJLgq?editors=100 this is the file above called view card
I have another file called catalogue which is where the user selects the books and then sends them to the viewcart page code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPrXPG?editors=100

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>View shopping cart</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>
<body>
<br>
<div id="books-wrapper">
<!-- #content to center the menu -->
<div id="content">
<!-- This is the actual menu -->
<ul id="darkmenu">
<li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="catalogue.php">Catalogue</a></li>
<li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
<li><a href= "view_cart.php">Cart</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
</ul>
<div id = "welcome" >
Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['login_user']?>! <br> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<h1 id = "mainHeader" >View Cart</h1>
<br>
<div class="view-cart">
<?php
$current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if(isset($_SESSION["books"]))
{
$total = 0;
echo '<form method="post" action="">';
echo '<ul>';
$cart_items = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION["books"] as $cart_itm){
$ISBN = $cart_itm["ISBN"];
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT Title,BookDesc,Price FROM books WHERE ISBN='$ISBN'");
$obj = $results->fetch_object();
echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["ISBN"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">×</a></span>';
echo '<div class="p-Price">'.$currency.$obj->Price.'</div>';
echo '<div class="book-info">';
echo '<h3>'.$obj->Title.' (ISBN :'.$ISBN.')</h3> ';
echo '<div class="p-quantity">Quantity : '.$cart_itm["quantity"].'</div>';
echo '<div>'.$obj->BookDesc.'</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</li>';
$subtotal = ($cart_itm["Price"]*$cart_itm["quantity"]);
$total = ($total + $subtotal);
echo '<input type="hidden" name="itemname_['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->Title.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="itemcode_['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$ISBN.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="itemdesc_['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->BookDesc.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="itemquantity_['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$cart_itm["quantity"].'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="total_['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$total.'" />';
$cart_items ++;
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '<span class="check-out-txt">';
echo '<strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong> ';
echo '</span>';
echo '<button name="submit_btn" class="save_order">Save Order</button>';
echo '</form>';
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']) ){
    $item_array = array();


    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
 // echo "POST parameter '$key' has '$value';
        $pieces = explode("_",$key)
        if(strstr($pieces[0] == 'itemname')
        {
            $item_array[$pieces[1]]['BookName'] = $value;

        }
        if(strstr($pieces[0] == 'itemcode')
        {
            $item_array[$pieces[1]]['ISBN'] = $value;
        }

        if(strstr($pieces[0] == 'itemquantity')
        {
            $item_array[$pieces[1]]['Quantity'] = $value;
        }
        if(strstr($pieces[0] == 'total')
        {
            $item_array[$pieces[1]]['TotalPrice'] = $value;
        }
}

$insquery = "INSERT INTO `pending_orders` (`OrderNo`,`BookName`,`Quantity`,`TotalPrice`,`ISBN`,`StudentID`) VALUES ";
foreach($item_array as $row)
{
    $insquery .= "(NULL, '" . $row['BookName'] . "', '" . $row['Quantity'] . "', '" .$row['TotalPrice']. "', '" . $row['ISBN'] . "', '" . $_SESSION['login_user'] . "'),";
}

$insquery = substr($insquery, 0, -1);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($insquery);
$stmt->execute();

    foreach($_POST as $row)
$insquery = "INSERT INTO `pending_orders` (`OrderNo`,`BookName`,`Quantity`,`TotalPrice`,`ISBN`,`StudentID`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $obj->Title . "', '" . $cart_itm['quantity'] . "', '" . $total . "', '" . $ISBN . "', '" . $_SESSION['login_user'] . "');";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($insquery);
$stmt->execute();
}
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

you  form the insert statement like above